# Ubuntu 22.04 network keeps disconnecting

Tags: networking, ethernet

The network connection in my Ubuntu keeps disconnecting. I have been running Ubuntu 18.04 without any problem. But when I upgraded to 22.04, the network is not stable, it keeps disconnecting.

I have pretty much tried all the solutions suggested for Realtek 8169/8168 issues.

I have compiled the kernel module r8168 from the source from Realtek. This is what I am using now. But the problem persists.

Here are some output.

```
$ sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B85 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 950] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)



$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: d8:cb:8a:7c:29:e8
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.050.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

Here is the syslog, about 100 lines, containing the full cycle of connecting and disconnecting.

```
Aug  9 07:27:34 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004854.0148] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug  9 07:27:41 eryd-MS-7850 kernel: [ 1465.847814] r8168: enp3s0: link down
Aug  9 07:27:42 eryd-MS-7850 google-chrome.desktop[3591]: [3585:3635:0809/072742.141251:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Aug  9 07:27:44 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004867.6392] device (enp3s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004867.6625] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004867.6626] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004867.6627] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed no lease
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.20 on enp3s0.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.20.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c on enp3s0.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004867.6918] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[926]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=927 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[926]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug  9 07:27:47 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 kernel: [ 1480.199062] r8168: enp3s0: link up
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9630] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9637] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9650] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (947deb8a-c0e0-3198-ba39-27d402838c7b)
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9654] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (947deb8a-c0e0-3198-ba39-27d402838c7b)
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9655] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9659] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9660] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9662] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004875.9667] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c.
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:27:55 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Registering new address record for fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c on enp3s0.*.
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0088] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.20
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.20.
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.20 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0114] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0130] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0133] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0135] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0138] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0139] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.0144] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 202.73.99.2, 118.136.64.5, 111.95.141.4
Aug  9 07:27:57 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004877.5251] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug  9 07:28:05 eryd-MS-7850 kernel: [ 1489.399148] r8168: enp3s0: link down
Aug  9 07:28:05 eryd-MS-7850 google-chrome.desktop[3591]: [3585:3635:0809/072805.692732:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(425)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Aug  9 07:28:07 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004891.1911] device (enp3s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004891.2064] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004891.2064] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004891.2064] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed no lease
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.20 on enp3s0.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.20.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c on enp3s0.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004891.2308] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[926]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=927 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[926]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug  9 07:28:11 eryd-MS-7850 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 kernel: [ 1503.750370] r8168: enp3s0: link up
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5144] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5149] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5162] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (947deb8a-c0e0-3198-ba39-27d402838c7b)
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5166] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (947deb8a-c0e0-3198-ba39-27d402838c7b)
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5167] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5168] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5170] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5173] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004899.5177] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c.
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:28:19 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Registering new address record for fe80::3086:833a:bbb2:159c on enp3s0.*.
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5561] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.20
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.20.
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 avahi-daemon[924]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.20 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5591] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5611] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5613] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5616] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5618] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5619] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004900.5623] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Aug  9 07:28:20 eryd-MS-7850 systemd-resolved[910]: enp3s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 202.73.99.2, 118.136.64.5, 111.95.141.4
Aug  9 07:28:21 eryd-MS-7850 NetworkManager[927]: <info>  [1660004901.0531] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

Comment: What solutions did you try?

Comment: Same troubles here, but on my side, i figured out, that the issue happens only, if i used my radius configured wifi lan, when i use the simply wpa2\wpa3 personal wifi it worked stable But the configuration was also stalbe before some updates with radius enabled network.
SystemD or kernel, both were updated, so i cannot say which one made the trouble maybe same at you??